# From/Since time immemorial

Tags: phrases, expressions

Which is correct? 'From' or 'Since' when applied to 'time immemorial'? I have seen both around, and have a feeling it might be 'from', but would like to check.

Comment: Believe it or not, [they're almost neck-to-neck](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from+time+immemorial%2C+since+time+immemorial&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20time%20immemorial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csince%20time%20immemorial%3B%2Cc0) now.

Answer (score 1):

> **[time immemorial](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/time-immemorial)** (n.)
>
> 1. Used to refer to a point of time in the past that was so long ago that people have no knowledge, memory, [or record of it]†.

> **[from](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/from)** (prep.)
>
> 2. Indicating the point in time at which a particular process, event, or activity starts [or had started]†.
>
> > ***From*** the time he was a young boy, he had wanted to rule the world.
> >
> > ***From*** time immemorial, human beings have been waging wars for one reason or another.

> **[since](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/since)** (prep.)
>
> 1. In the intervening period between (the time mentioned) and the time under consideration, typically the present.
>
> > ***Since*** the fall of the Berlin Wall in 1989, Germany has seen unprecedented economic growth and success.
> >
> > *While science has proven that humans have been irreparably damaging the Earth, one could argue that the Earth had already been dying **since** time immemorial.*

With these definitions and examples in mind, we could determine that the use of *from time immemorial* and *since time immemorial* could both be correct depending on the context. However it should be noticed that historically, *from time immemorial* has not only seen greater historical use, but it is also a fixture of English Law, stating it being a time "[beyond legal memory; that is, the time prior to the commencement of the reign of Richard I., A.D. 1189.](https://books.google.com/books?id=Mu0XAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA341&ots=oLv-0787Nn&dq=beyond%20legal%20memory%2C%20fixed%20by%20statute%20as%20prior%20to%201189%2C%20the%20beginning%20of%20the%20reign%20of%20Richard%20I&pg=PA341#v=onepage&q=beyond%20legal%20memory,%20fixed%20by%20statute%20as%20prior%20to%201189,%20the%20beginning%20of%20the%20reign%20of%20Richard%20I&f=false)"

---

<sup>† My enhancements to these definitions are [in the brackets].</sup>

Answer (score -4):

[Since](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/since) is always used with a definite point of time, like *since yesterday* or *since morning*, so I think *since time immemorial* is wrong and *from time immemorial* is right.

Comment: This post is poorly written and has errors.  It has no documentation or explanation for your answer.